# brush selection in scatterplot matrix example in d3.js is offset?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, brush

I am using the scatterplot matrix example in d3.js. I have successfully used it with my data. However I noticed that when I use the mouse crosshairs to begin selection of an area to highlight the points within, the start point of the selection region is offset from where I click. How do I fix this? Here is a link and a screenshot for the example
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663:

[image]

Comment: Works for me in the example. It's a bit difficult to see because the cursor is quite large.

Comment: The cursor is cross shaped, so if I start at the intersection of a grid lines, the region selected is offset to the right and down as compared to the start point. On further testing, this is a problem in Firefox. It works perfectly in the Chrome browser.

Comment: did you happen to solve this problem, @user3203010?

Comment: @VividD Yes the change suggested by Cihad Turhan fixed the issue in Firefox, while not affecting selection in the Chrome browser. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked on Mozilla and found that the following property in [the main file](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063663/94244f5d8aff0ddd19462c258feca668b46296ff/)

```
svg {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

changing padding to 0px make the code run happily. If you need padding, you may add margin as a workaround.